# Android app not showing any error but crash on startup?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am pretty much new to android development. I am trying to make a wallpaper app but it crashes both on emulator and a real device (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini).
This is my MainActivity (only a part of it I actually have over 50 images)

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.WallpaperManager;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
ImageButton image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, 
ImageView display;
Button set;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
    onClick();
}

public void initialize(){

    image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    image3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    image4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    image5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    image6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    image7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    image8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    image9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button9);

}
public void onClick() {


    image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);    



            }
    });
    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);    
        }
    });
    image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);    
        }
    });
```

my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.acmilanwallpapersblueball"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"    android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.acmilanwallpapersblueball.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I already tried several things to fix the problem but it still crashes every time. I made few different applications with code similar to this but every one of them crashes.

Comment: Open LogCat and view the logs

Comment: Check `logcat` output, it shows logs and exceptions (if any).

Comment: you have `setContentView` more than once in the same activity. not a good design

Comment: yes... as @Raghunandan said instead of inflating the view again, what about using Fragments. :)

Comment: @user restrart your eclipse and select device in which you are running your app and try again, you can see logcat.

Answer (score 4):

`ImageView display` is not initialized. Also you `setContentView` more than once in the same activity which is not a good design.

Also `findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. So you are probably getting NPE. Not sure whether display is in `activity_main.xml` or `second.xml`

`Button set` is also  not initialized.

```
I actually have over 50 images
```

You can use listview with LazyLoading

Comment: i initialize display with:
display.setImageResource..
Should I start a new activity every time when image is pressed?

Comment: @user3065971 yes you should

Comment: @user3065971 actually have over 50 images. why not use a listview and lazy loading.http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. Download BitmapFun and use it